# extract an array from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So here is my array:

> array(1) { [0]=> string(79) "{"form_array":{"element1":"value1","element2":"value2","element3":"value3"}}" }

How can I extract "form_array" as an array?

Comment: That is not an array, that is a string.

Comment: Looks like json in a array to me @Mihai Iorga

Comment: weird, it doesn't to me :|, today I'm kinda .. blind. Late for work, tripped on stairs, dropped my coffee.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga Looking at it again ... that does not look like `print_r` or `var_dump` output ..... where did you get hat pt0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have just a simple array with one element, which is a string, that seems to be JSON encoded. To get its data, you may use the following:

```
// get the string
$data = $array[0];

// decode the content
$data = json_decode( $data, true );

// get the sub array
$data = $data['form_array'];
```

<sub>The steps may of course be simplified into a single row. I just separated them for readability and clarity.</sub>

Comment: Correct, that was the json in an array.


Thanks Sirko, I just altered for other people having the same.

$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$array = json_decode($array[0]);
$formArray = $array->form_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have posted the result of var_dump(arrayname), then this code only will help you

```
$data = $data['form_array'];
```

else you can go with Sirko's anser

Comment: I guess you should take the first index of the array like Sirko did.